# YouTube clears the comment after Chrome closes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to leave a comment under a certain video, and then edit it after a certain period of time.
The program works and does everything as it should, but after the program ends the comment disappears. How can I fix this?

```
from time import sleep
import time, datetime
from random import randint
import threading

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

YOUTUBE_VIDEO = 'https://www.youtube.com/change_link'
EMAIL = ''
PASSWORD = ''
COMMENT = 'comment'


def delay(n):
    sleep(randint(2, n))


def skipAdFunction(skipAd):
    threading.Timer(3, skipAdFunction).start()
    if (skipAd.is_enabled() or skipAd.is_displayed()):
        skipAd.click()


def main():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Arteefal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.get(YOUTUBE_VIDEO)

    sleep(1)
    duration_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']")[0].text
    date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(duration_text, "%M:%S")
    video_duration_in_seconds = (date_time - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

    sleep(2)
    try:
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-ad-skip-button-container')
        button.click()
    except:
        pass

    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    sleep(2)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-comments ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer")))

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-comments ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer div#placeholder-area").click()
    my_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenteditable-root"]')
    my_comment.send_keys('начал смотреть видос!')
    my_comment.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER)

    print('Ждем ', video_duration_in_seconds, ' секунд.')
    sleep(video_duration_in_seconds)

    menu = my_comment.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='style-scope ytd-comment-renderer' and @id='action-menu']")
    sleep(2)
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu)
    hover.perform()
    menu.click()

    sleep(1)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer']")))
    menu.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer']").click()
    modified_comment = menu.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/ytd-app/div[@id='content']/ytd-page-manager[@id='page-manager']/ytd-watch-flexy[@class='style-scope ytd-page-manager hide-skeleton']/div[@id='columns']/div[@id='primary']/div[@id='primary-inner']/div[@id='below']/ytd-comments[@id='comments']/ytd-item-section-renderer[@id='sections']/div[@id='contents']/ytd-comment-thread-renderer[@class='style-scope ytd-item-section-renderer'][1]/ytd-comment-renderer[@id='comment']/div[@id='edit-dialog']/ytd-comment-dialog-renderer[@class='style-scope ytd-comment-renderer']/ytd-commentbox[@id='commentbox']/div[@id='thumbnail-input-row']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='creation-box']/tp-yt-paper-input-container[@id='input-container']/div[@class='input-wrapper style-scope tp-yt-paper-input-container']/div[@id='labelAndInputContainer']/div[@class='paper-input-input style-scope ytd-commentbox'][1]/ytd-emoji-input[@id='emoji']/yt-user-mention-autosuggest-input[@class='style-scope ytd-commentbox']/yt-formatted-string[@id='contenteditable-textarea']/div[@id='contenteditable-root']")
    modified_comment.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.HOME)
    modified_comment.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    modified_comment.send_keys(COMMENT)
    modified_comment.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER)

    print('Готово')
    sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to leave a comment under a certain video, and then edit it after a certain period of time.
The program works and does everything as it should, but after the program ends the comment disappears. How can I fix this?